# NoMethodError - undefined method 'update' for InlineTextStorage:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem with the method `update`. When I call him in the controller I fail `NoMethodError - undefined method 'update' for InlineTextStorage:Class`
What could be the reason?

```
class StaticAreasController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @static_area = InlineTextStorage.update("key", "value")
  end
end

class InlineTextStorage
  def update(key, value)
    inline_text = StaticArea.find_by_key!(key)
    inline_text.text = value
    @@texts[key] = value
    update_cache
  end
end
```

Comment: Try changing this `def update(key, value)` to `def self.update(key, value)` in your `InlineTextStorage` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call an instance method as a class method. You have to add a `self.` in the name.

```
class InlineTextStorage
  def self.update(key, value)
    inline_text = StaticArea.find_by_key!(key)
```

This way the method is accessible from the class.